# Crittercism Android - Does not always post crash report to Server

Tags: android, crittercism

I have a android app in which Crittercism SDK is included and initialised as per standard documentation.

I intentionally put a loophole in the flow by which I can make app crash by manipulating data on my server and then pushing it to device.

Recently few users reported crash but I didnot see it on Crittercism website. So I simulated crashes. Out of 3 crashes I got report for 2 on Crittercism website and one was missed.

I waited for a day. And since 2 crashes made through, there is no issue with sdk integration in my app. (Its not NDK and crashes were of type malformed JSON during parsing) Not related to Java runtime crashes or other low level crashes.

Does any one face similar issue? How can we avoid this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue, but it concerned the automatic emails that you receive when a crash occurs. I found that identical crashes are usually only reported once.

The following Crittercism KB article explains why:

http://support.crittercism.com/articles/knowledge_base/Im-not-getting-an-email-every-time-the-app-crashes-whats-happening